# cannot find zipalign.exe from android sdk

Tags: android-studio, sdk, ionic2

what do I need to download to get the zip-align tool to use on my apk file?
I am using the ionic3 guide for developing for Android. when I type this:

```
zip-align -v 4 android-release-unsigned. apk HelloWorld.apk
```

I get:

```
'zip-align' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I want to build for google playstore

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You will found zipalign.exe in this location

C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\build-tools{android-api-no}\zipalign.exe

then you need to add in your system path

Windows

Windows 10 and Windows 8
In Search, search for and then select: System (Control Panel)
Click the Advanced system settings link.
Click Environment Variables. In the section System Variables, find the PATH environment variable and select it. Click Edit. If the PATH environment variable does not exist, click New.
In the Edit System Variable (or New System Variable) window, specify the value of the PATH environment variable: 'zipalign'. Click OK. Close all remaining windows by clicking OK.

more info how to change path:
https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

Answer (score 1):

- Download the 20.0.0 version file from this link
  https://androidsdkmanager.azurewebsites.net/Buildtools
- After Extract, you can find Zipalign.exe file in it & Copy that file & paste it in tools & bin folder.
- Restart Eclipse & thats how it works for me.